# Why is my timer Observable never called?

Tags: android, rx-java

On Android, I have written an `Observable` which should be called once after 2000 msec, but which is never called.

```
    Observable.timer(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // wait 2000 msec
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<?>>() {

        @Override public Observable<?> call(Long aLong) {
            continuePlayback(); // this line is never called
            return null;
        }

    });
```

I want the `Observable` to wait off the main thread, then call `continuePlayback()` on the main thread. Context help allowed me to place `subscribeOn/observeOn` between the `timer` and `flatMap`. Is this correct? What is really happening here and what did I do wrong?

What happens to the `Observable` after the call? Will it stay alive or will I need to explicitly tear it down somehow, e.g. call `OnCompleted()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most `Obsersables` are passive by default and they will only emit items if they are subscribed to.  In your code example you're not subscribing to your `Observable`.  Therefore it never actually starts emitting items or in this case the only items after 2000 milliseconds.

`flatMap` is simply an `Operator` to help manipulate the stream of data but it doesn't subscribe to your stream of `Observables`.

Instead of using `flatMap` you should replace it with a call to `subscribe`.

```
Observable.timer(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Long aLong) {
            continuePlayback();
        }
    });
```

I used the `Action` instead of an `Observer` in the `subscribe` since I don't believe you'll need to handle `onError` in this particular case.

The `Observable` from `timer` will complete after emitting it's only item.

Keep in mind that if you're using `Observables` from within a `Fragment` or an `Activity` you should always make sure you `unsubscribe` from your `Observables` to eliminate chances of memory leaks.

Here's a quick link to the [Hot and Cold Observables in RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Observable#hot-and-cold-observables)

Comment: This works perfectly fine but it raised the question how you would write an Observable then which emits without any subscribers attached. What would change if I wanted to emit regularly? Just use interval() instead of timer()? Who tells me if an Observable starts emitting immediately or only when a subscriber has subscribed?

Comment: `Subjects` are an example of Hot `Observable`. They don't need to be subscribed to in order for their `onNext` to be called.  I would suggest reading this http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html.  It was written with .NET but still applies to RxJava.