# How to unsubscribe from an Observable when using an Android library

Tags: android, rx-java

In [Why is my timer Observable never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197386/why-is-my-timer-observable-never-called/26197716#26197716) 
@Miguel Lavigne says:

"Keep in mind that if you're using Observables from within a Fragment or an Activity you should always make sure you unsubscribe from your Observables to eliminate chances of memory leaks."

It is clear to me how it works as long as I am using an Observable in an Activity, Fragment or View. But what if I am using it where there is no context?

My situation: I am having an external library which holds an object model. Each object has a .save() function, which is called from the UI. In save, an API endpoint call is performed by an Observable asynchronously.

Example:

```
public Overlay save() {
        Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Overlay>() {

        @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Overlay> subscriber) {
            try {
                Overlay overlay= OverlayEndpoint.insertOverlay(this); // call the API endpoint here
                subscriber.onNext(overlay);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }

    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Overlay>() {

                @Override public void call(Overlay overlay) {
                    // process the saved result [omitted for brevity]
                }

            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {

                @Override public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    // put the overlay into a local upload queue in case the endpoint is unreachable [omitted]
                }

            });

    return this; // return the call immediately
}
```

The Observable is for one-time use within save and becomes obsolete thereafter. How can I make sure it does not persist?

Situation 1: Normal unsubscribe. Is there a way to unsubscribe right from within the call(), once processing is complete?

Situation 2: For whatever reason the Observable stays in memory. Could I use .timeout() to ensure the Observable is destroyed after enough time has passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Situation 1: Normal unsubscribe. Is there a way to unsubscribe right from within the call(), once processing is complete?

In your case, `Observable` will be in memory before `Action1<Overlay>` or `new Action1<Throwable>` is called. But after one of them is called, GC should be able to clean the `Observable`.

> Situation 2: For whatever reason the Observable stays in memory. Could I use .timeout() to ensure the Observable is destroyed after enough time has passed?

In your case, `Schedulers.newThread()` will create a new `Thread` to run the `Observable.OnSubscribe<Overlay>.call`. So if this method has not returned yet, such as `OverlayEndpoint.insertOverlay` will run about 10 minutes, `Observable` can not be cleaned by GC because this thread is still using it. There is nothing we can do unless there is an approach to cancel `OverlayEndpoint.insertOverlay`.